# MongoRepository method that returns the distance between item location and a specific point

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongo

I have two entities:

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

}

@Document(collection = "items")
public class Item implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private User user;

    @GeoSpatialIndexed(type = GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
    private GeoJsonPoint location;

}
```

And I want to find all items that reference a specific user and somehow return the distance between a point and item location.

```
public interface ItemRepository extends MongoRepository<Item, String> {

    Page<Item> findByUserId(String userId, Pageable pageable);

}
```

How can I change `findByUserId` method declaration to return also the distance between item location and some point (that maybe can be passed as a parameter)?

I have tried GeoPage without success.